# array functions: how to sum over date range?

Tags: excel

We have a rather complex array issue we are trying to overcome:

This is the standard array formula we are using to sum various columns according to a single parameters being met, in this case the value $k$6, being within the F column.

```
=SUM(('EVERYTHING PIVOT'!$F$5:$F$100000=$K$6)*('EVERYTHING PIVOT'!$K$5:$K$100000))
```

However, we now wish to sum values over that group of dates that is 30 days previous to the latest date in the range.

The values will satisfy this condition in the date column A:

```
">"&MAX($A$5:$A$100000)-30
```

However I can't see a way of integrating it into the the first array formula as an additional parameter, as array formulas can only use single values and not ranges..

I there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off with SUMIF like this for your original, i.e.

`=SUMIF('EVERYTHING PIVOT'!$F$5:$F$100000,$K$6,'EVERYTHING PIVOT'!$K$5:$K$100000)`

If you have Excel 2007 or later (and presumably you do, otherwise you couldn't use 100,000 rows) you can then add a criterion in `SUMIFS` function, i.e.

`=SUMIFS('EVERYTHING PIVOT'!$K$5:$K$100000,'EVERYTHING PIVOT'!$F$5:$F$100000,$K$6,'EVERYTHING PIVOT'!$A$5:$A$100000,">"&MAX($A$5:$A$100000)-30)`

Note the syntax of SUMIFS is different, the sum range is at the start

in older versions of excel you can revise your array formula like this

`=SUM(('EVERYTHING PIVOT'!$F$5:$F$100000=$K$6)*('EVERYTHING PIVOT'!$K$5:$K$100000)*('EVERYTHING PIVOT'!$A$5:$A$100000>MAX($A$5:$A$100000)-30
))`

Comment: very informative: kind regards for this.. will try the array adjustment too.

Comment: One final note:  This only worked when we also had >MAX('EVERYTHING PIVOT'!$A$5:$A$100000)-30       I.E dont forget to get the correct sheet inside the MAX function

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Excel 2007 or later, consider using `SUMIFS`

```
=SUMIFS('EVERYTHING PIVOT'!$K:$K,
        'EVERYTHING PIVOT'!$F:$F,$K$6,
        'EVERYTHING PIVOT'!$A:$A,">"&MAX('EVERYTHING PIVOT'!$A:$A)-30)
```

`SUMIFS` Adds the cells in a range that meet multiple criteria

```
SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)
```

If using excel 2003 or earlier you can do a similar thing with `SUMPRODUCT`

Comment: I think we were answering with roughly the same suggestion at the same time, Chris +1 for using whole column refs....

Comment: wow! I didn't know this had been introduced.. will have a go!